# Executing Linux command via PHP on web host?

Tags: php, linux, shell, flash

I'm using [flare](http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html) to decompile a flash movie. I need to do it via PHP. User visits PHP script, it decompiles the flash movie.

Here is how the files are set up on my web host: [image]

index.php:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(-1);
    echo shell_exec('./flare movie.swf');
?>
```

Flare is supposed to create a file named movie.flr once the script runs, but there is no such file. I am thinking my shell_exec is wrong.

phpinfo() - http://zachafer.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: You're trying to execute a tarball?

Comment: Best practice: always test in local first. You are trying to execute a script from a PHP script while you do not even know how to use it directly !

Comment: I only have access to a windows server.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to execute the wrong file.
**flare.tgz** is an archive (not executable) containing the **flare** binary (executable).

Unpack it with an archiver tool like winrar on windows or tar on linux (*tar xvf flare.tgz*).
Inside the archive, you will find a file named **flare**. Try with this one and it might work if your host provider allow the shell_exec() function calls.

Comment: Thanks - I have extracted it. I am pretty sure my shell_exec command is wrong. I am unfamiliar with Linux command line

Comment: According to the flare documentation, your command line seems to be ok.

Comment: `System Linux cpanel03.myhostcenter.com 2.6.32-131.17.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 29 10:24:25 EDT 2011 x86_64`

Should I use the the Linux x86 binary or the Linux x86 64-bit binary?

Comment: The Linux x86 64-bit one. Do you have a SSH access to the server to try to execute the command manually ? Check that the directory containing these files is writable by the web server.

Comment: I only have FTP access. The folder containing the files is CHMOD to 755, flare is CHMOD 777, movie.swf is CHMOD 777, the PHP script is CHMOD 755

Comment: Ok, the problem may be at the directory level : if the webserver is running with another user than yours, it will not be allowed to write in your directory. Try to **temporary** set your directory writable by everyone to see if its a writing permission problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9283/discussion-between-zed-and-maaaaat)

Answer (score 1):

You can't execute a .tgz file directly!  You need to unpack the executable before you can run it.

Answer (score 0):

This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode... check it or ask your host provider about it

Comment: According to my phpinfo(), safe_mode is Off

Comment: In your file system flare `movie.swf` does not exist there is only `movie.swf`

Comment: try this shell_exec('./movie.swf')

Comment: `flare` is the script, `movie.swf` is the file parameter

Comment: and shell_exec takes command string as its argument... try execute this command shel_exec("xdg-open ./movie.swf")

Comment: the shell command to open the file with default editor is xdg-open ./file.ext try it

Comment: I'm not trying to open `movie.swf` - I'm trying to open `flare` with the parameter of `movie.swf`

Answer (score 0):

I think `flare.tgz` is not an executable but a `.tar.gz` file (it's like a zip file, but it is another format).

You have to unpack it first !